# asp.net GoogleCloud Firestore credentails not available

Tags: c#, asp.net, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to follow this  [tutorial](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Firestore/index.html) to connect to Firestore but i got this error

> "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The Application Default
>   Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google
>   Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable
>   GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file
>   defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/"

They dont explain how to Authenticate to use the FireStore. Can you please let me know how to do it and avoid this error.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you been able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [tutorial](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Firestore/index.html) you linked does point to the authentication mechanism, which is [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started).

In summary you will have to do following-

1. Create a Service account **for your project** from [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/serviceaccountkey). Make Sure the service account has appropriate **Role** assigned so that it has permission to access firestore.
2. Create and download a **service account key file** for that service account.
3. Save the key file in a secure **location** in your server.
4. Create an ***environment variable*** named **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** in your server, and use the file location of the key file as it's value.
   For example, using powershell-

> $env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\username\Downloads\service-account-file.json"

After that, requests will be automatically authenticated using those information.

Remember that You must keep your downloaded service account key absolutely secure and not distribute it.

Also as per the library documentation, if your server is in Google Cloud Platform, no action needs to be taken to authenticate.

Comment: Thank you for the solution.